# How to Transpose Rows to Columns Dynamically in MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

As per the attached images, each orderId will have  transactions and should come as output as shown in the second image.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when tiid = ''',
      tiid,
      ''' then amount end) ' ,concat('T',tiid)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Test;
  
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT poid, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Test 
                  WHERE amount is not null
                   GROUP BY poid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I have used the above code but getting the output in different format as shown below.
[image]

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: The query output is in line with your data. It seems that you would like to show tid 4 and 5 under 1 and 2 respectively. What about even higher tid values?

Comment: For example if a pid has 3 transactions it has to come under T1,T2,T3
if a pid has 2 transactions it has to come under T1,T2.
Please consider the tid as transactions.

Comment: I have added more poid's to give  more clarity about my query ,Kindly help